# jQuery bounce effect issue

Tags: jquery, animation, bounce

I am trying to use jQuery's bounce effect on a few images. When I hover over the images you see the bounce working once. but if you mouse out and want roll over the images again the images won't bounce anymore. and every once in awhile it throws a js error but it's not consistent. "b.callback.apply is not a function". Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWrzM/3/

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra {,} your arguments for the effect()

```
$('img.hp_icons').hover(function() {
$(this).effect("bounce", {
    distance: 10,
    times: 3
}, 500);
});
```